# Getting CallOutException in salesforce:"Attempt to use invalid header in request"

Tags: apex, callout, apexrest

We are trying to make a callout to the third party application using ClientId and SecretCode but getting the error at the line assigning the header (req.setHeader).

Tried with BASIC as well also included Accept in the header but no luck. Can't move after req.setHeader, values are not null and everything is present, not sure where and why this exception is caused here.

Code Snippet:-

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
string endPointValue = 'https://api.XXXX.com/api/oauth/token';
req.setEndpoint(endPointValue); 
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
//req.setHeader('accept','application/json'); 
// error is there even if including accept.
String authString = ClientID + ':' + SecretCode;
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(authString);
String authHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);           
req.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);        
String body = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=' + VCode +'&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI;       
req.setBody(body);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

Debug Log:

> ```
> SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[113]|System.HttpRequest.setHeader(String, String)
> 15:42:46.0 (2506000)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[113]|System.CalloutException: Attempt to use invalid header in request
> ```

Comment: What kind of characters do you have in the `ClientID` and `SecretCode`? Are they just alpha-numeric, or something more exotic? I'm wondering if there is an issue with the base 64 encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked just fine for me in anonymous apex.

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
string endPointValue = 'https://api.XXXX.com/api/oauth/token';
req.setEndpoint(endPointValue); 
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setHeader('accept','application/json'); 

string ClientID = 'foo+bar';
string SecretCode = 'new\nline';

// error is there even if including accept.
String authString = ClientID + ':' + SecretCode;
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(authString);
String authHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);           
req.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
```

That you are getting an exception when calling the `HttpRequest.setHeader(String, String)` method on the last line is really odd.

The only thing I can think of is some sort of issue with the base64 encoding of the `ClinetID` and `SecretCode`. Do they contain any exotic characters, such as Ascii control codes?

Comment: Very good with the ClientId and ConsumerKey ( checked in Debug logs).

Comment: @HRZ Sorry, I don't follow. Are you saying the values in those two variables look fine? I don't want to know the exact values (and nor should you tell me what they are), but can you try simplified values like in my example to see if it at least gets you past the error.